# Decrypting intercepted wpa2 traffic

Tags: network

If you have the wpa2 network key/password how difficult/time-consuming is it to decrypt the trrafic.

Comment: I answered this question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/101889/6276

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple wireshark has a feature were you select a packet dump. You can then enter a wpa-psk key the second you enter that all data will be decrypted in packet capture.

Reference/Tutorial: https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

Comment: This is not exactly true. It works only this way when it comes to WEP but in WPA2 the traffice is encrypted with a session specific key that is exchanged in the process of the handshake. Because of that you can only decrypt the traffic of the clients their handshake you captured too...